# Wordpress and jquery conflicts in template header

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

I have a website that seems to be having some issues with either the version of jquery or some kind of conflict. The theme I modified uses the `wp_enqueue_script` technique in the header, but the site is so slow to load and a plugin I use for banners on the home page is not working correctly, mainly it shows all banners at once covering the page until it starts fading through them as it should. I cannot get past the idea that this has to do with Wordpress/jQuery conflicts, but I don't know for sure. The website is [familyeducationandsupport.org](http://www.familyeducationandsupport.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is slow because you're loading a huge number of scripts and CSS, some of your thumbnail images are too large and are being resized, and you've got hundreds of CSS errors and some JS errors. And that banner is loading all the way down the page. Why are you loading the jQuery Tabs UI? Are you using all those libraries?

The pixopoint menu plugin is probably unnecessary; you should use the WP3 menu system, which is more efficient in terms of JS and CSS for the menus.

And you're on GoDaddy, which is another reason the site is slow.

Use  [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's happening with the site. And see [How to load JavaScript like a WordPress Master](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)

Comment: Problems, problems and more problems. I blame most on the template itself and my cherry knowledge on the subject. Your insight on the issues are very much appreciated :) I will look at your suggestions and check on those errors. Thanks again! P.S. - I wholeheartedly agree with the godaddy comment. We have many clients hosted on their servers and while great at first, they have slowly been deteriorating as far as reliability goes.